# Control template and theme-related data separation through the Resource Dictionaries

Tags: silverlight, xaml, themes, resourcedictionary

I have several resource dictionaries with theme-related data, where I declared styles for particular element this way:

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataForm">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Bckgrnd}"/>
</Style>
```

And also I have Generic.xaml, where I want to set the template for this target type, but I was faced with a situation where in one template I have to use several colors but target type have only one property for color. Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataForm">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataForm">
                <Grid ctl:DataField.IsFieldGroup="True">
                    ....
                 <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...>
                    ...
                    ...
                 <!-- and I need another background from themes here -->
                 <StackPanel Background="{???}" ...>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the question is: how can I use different colors in this case without something like target type extension? It will be great if you'll find pure xaml solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a pure XAML solution. I think I would create a subclass of DataForm and add dependency properties of type Brush to it. Then use that class in the XAML instead of DataForm, and use TemplateBindings that reference the new properties.

Or, if you don't want to subclass DataForm, perhaps you could create attached properties of type Brush.